# error to compress multiples image file and donwload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm rookie to this new world of programming and need some help with express-zip and node.js

i'm able to make a single download of an image from instagram, but, when the user pastes a link that contains 2 o 3 or more images, the server stops.

So, i tried to implement express-zip to put all the media inside of it and download.

what happens is that when the download starts, he never finish and the size of the file is like, 66bytes

here my code

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const instaAPI = require("igdown-scrapper");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const app = express();
let data;
const port = 3000;
let arrayDocs = [];
let zip = require("express-zip");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.post("/download", async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.body.url;
  console.log(url);
  if (!url || !url.startsWith("https://www.instagram.com/")) {
    res.render("index", { error: "Invalid URL" });
    return;
  }

  instaAPI(url).then((response) => {
    data = response;
    console.log(data.length);
    if (data.length > 1) {
      let count = data.length;
      // console.log(data[0].url[0]);

      if (data[0].url[0].ext == "mp4") {
        for (x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        //   multipleDownloads(x, data[x].url[0].url, "mp4");

          arrayDocs.push({ path: `${data[x].url[0].url}`, name: Date.now() + `${x}.` + "mp4" })

          if (x === data.length - 1) {
            console.log("Zip file send")
           
            res.zip(arrayDocs);
        } 
        else{
            continue;
        }
        }
      } else {
        for (x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        //   multipleDownloads(x, data[x].url[0].url, "jpg");

          arrayDocs.push({ path: `${data[x].url[0].url}.jpg`, name: Date.now() + `${x}.` + "jpg" })

          if (x === data.length - 1) {
            console.log("Zip file send")
            console.log(arrayDocs);
            res.zip(arrayDocs);
        } 
        else{
            continue;
        }
        }
      }
    } else if (data.url[0].ext == "mp4") {
      downloadFile(res, data.url[0].url, "mp4");
    } else {
      downloadFile(res, data.url[0].url, "jpg");
    }
  });
});

async function downloadFile(res, url, ext) {
  request(url, { encoding: null }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
      res.status(400).send("Error downloading image");
      return;
    }

    const fileName = Date.now() + "." + ext;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`);
    res.send(body);
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("App is listening on port 3000");
});
```

make the express-zip integration work with instagram medias

Comment: Why are you defining `data` at the top-level? Same for `arrayDocs`. That's going to cause concurrency issues. You might as well just use `instaAPI(url).then((data) =>`

Comment: I'm defining it at the top level because I can use it wherever I want without declaring it again. This part is fully functional, the consoles.log I used assured me that the data I pass into express-zip is correct.

Comment: the "data" variable is being used to receive the response value.

And the variable "arrayDocs" is just an empty array where I put the documents using the push that is used later by express-zip